# How to create an axis with relative position to other axis?

Tags: matplotlib, axes, colorbar

I have several `fcontour` plots, each with a colorbar. For the colorbar I'm creating extra axis. It is possible to set the position of the colorbar axis relative to their fcontour axis?
Im only able to set the position from axis relative to the figure. Thanks!

Comment: To be very pendantic, matplotlib makes a distinction between `Axis` (1D thing, has limits, a transfrom (ex log vs linear) tick locators and label foramatters) and `Axes` (2D things, have 2 `Axis` as children that you can add `Artists` to.  You want to be talking about `axes` here, not axis.

Comment: And look in `mpl_toolkit.axes_grid` (iirc) which has a whole slew of higher-level tools like this (that are sadly, poorly documented).

Comment: Do you have an idea how to change the height from the colorbar using http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#colorbar-whose-height-or-width-in-sync-with-the-master-axes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the docs about [`mpl_toolkit.axes_grid`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#colorbar-whose-height-or-width-in-sync-with-the-master-axes) as tcaswell suggested, I used `divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)` and `cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="4.45%", pad=0.07,aspect = True)`. Usually `divider.append_axes` appends an axes with the same height to your plot, but as it seems you can change that setting `aspect = True`, and then modifying the aspect via `cax.set_aspect` and the size of your new axes.

The result is a colorbar which ALWAYS is beside its plot, and in my case it is a little shorter than the plot itself.
thanks tcaswell! :D